# VB - progress bar not incrementing correct amounts?

Tags: vb.net

I've got a program that's got some variables. I'm trying to interact the variables and make them show a visual perspective of time by using them to increment the progress bar.

A rendition of the code:

```
Dim count As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
Dim _toProgress As Integer = 100 / count
ProgressBar1.Increment(_toProgress)
```

I've got this all in a loop, so "_toProgress" is added on after a process (in a loop) has been completed...

That's basically the code I have simplified.
The problem is that when I increment the progress bar, it finished before it's supposed to.

e.g:
I've got a loop completing 175 process:
100 / 175 = 0.5714285714285714
So, _toProgress should equal '0.5714285714285714'.
Once one of the processes has been completed, it adds '_toProgress' to the incrementation (ProgressBar1.Increment(_toProgress)).

I know the '_toProgress' integer is correct, because '0.5714285714285714' * 175 = 100.

So I have no clue why the progress bar completes before it's supposed to, any clues?

Comment: Its probably because _toProgress is an Integer instead of a double.  Integer will always be a whole number.

Comment: As @Andrew said change declration of _toProgress to double.

Comment: That makes so much sense now. Thank you Andrew.

Comment: There's more than one flaw here.  If you progressed just a little and only added *one* item to the listbox then you increment by 100.  The simple way is ProgressBar1.Value = 100 * count / 175.  There's nothing special about the Increment() method, it doesn't make it "better".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only increment a ProgressBar in Integer increments.

The easiest solution is to change the `Maximum` property of the ProgressBar to the number of processes that you have and then increment by 1.

For example:

```
ProgressBar1.Maximum = ListBox1.Items.Count
ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, I thought it would be more elegant and look more realistic to increment it the way I proposed at first. Thank you.

Comment: @user3102516: Well, the problem is that you can only increment in integer chunks, so you will have many cases where the progressbar doesn't actually update when something happens. By incrementing by 1, the progressbar will update smoothly and accurately for each item in the count. I think that this approach will actually look much more natural and elegant than the original proposal.

Comment: you're right. It's still incrementing by the same amount whether it's by 1 or 100/listbox.items.count. So either way it's going to look the same, thanks a lot :)